# retrieving and comparing xml data

Tags: javascript, xml

In the following code, i am submitting 'suburb' value through HTML form 
then this value match with the suburb of 'address' element of xml file. which i have done and it showing all addresses of that suburb on google map
but i need to display just two addresses of that suburb that offer less rent.

Comment: What is your criteria for selecting two addresses?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler the criteria is that to find two cheapest properties( less rent) in that suburb.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you need to take in order to get the two cheapest rental properties are:

1. Get all properties within the your specified location into an array.
2. Sort the array based on price of the rent.
3. Take the first two items of the array.

Comment: as there no associative array in javascript , then how can i do this?

Comment: JavaScript objects essentially *are* associative arrays. Either way, why does that matter? Normal, index-based arrays can be sorted, too. It's just a matter of picking a value to sort on.

Comment: i used an array and sorted it as above but dont know how to stop it on the first two cheapest properties addresses

Comment: What do you mean by "stop" it? You have to sort the entire array on rental price. When all the items are sorted, the cheapest two properties are the first two items in the array.